# How do I recover lost folders and files in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, files, data-recovery

I'm a relative newbie to Ubuntu. I was trying to uninstall and re-install some Java programs on my setup and I ran the following command on the terminal

`for g in ControlPanel java java_vm javaws jcontrol jexec keytool mozilla-javaplugin.so orbd pack200 policytool rmid rmiregistry servertool tnameserv unpack200 appletviewer apt extcheck HtmlConverter idlj jar jarsigner javac javadoc javah javap jconsole jdb jhat jinfo jmap jps jrunscript jsadebugd jstack jstat jstatd native2ascii rmic schemagen serialver wsgen wsimport xjc xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so; do sudo update-alternatives --remove-all $g; done`

After I did this all my default folders(Desktop, Pictures, etc) and my files have disappeared. What can I do to undo this?

Comment: "undo" is different from "data-recovery". Which are you asking for? Is your system destroyed or not?

Comment: see `man update-java-alternatives`